# How to filter with multiple input field / dropdowns / select boxes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with server-side filtering. I have 3 different dropdowns, which every single one relate to a column. The user can select one, two or three dropdowns. The selected values are saved in variables and linked to SQL/ the Query.

I tried something like this below. It's obviously not working right, but I just want to show you the idea of the possibilities the user can select.

How can I filter the three columns (resp, customer, sn) on different conditions?

```sql
WHERE (resp='{{v_var_resp}}' and customer='{{v_var_type}}'  and sn='{{v_var_sn}}')
or  (resp='{{v_var_resp}}' and customer='{{v_var_type}}')
or  (resp='{{v_var_resp}}' and sn='{{v_var_sn}}')
or  (customer='{{v_var_type}}'  and sn='{{v_var_sn}}')
or  (resp='{{v_var_resp}}')
or  (customer='{{v_var_type}}')
or  (sn='{{v_var_sn}}')
```

Comment: This looks like you are injecting your parameters; I *hope* not as that's a severe and fatal security flaw.

Comment: Looks like what you want is a [Catch-all Query](https://www.sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/)/[Kitchen Sink Query](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example).

Comment: Ty Thom, this was it. Now its working!